# Is the word "вечер" pronounced like "ˈvʲet͡ɕɨr" even though the IPA for it is "ˈvʲet͡ɕɪr"?

Tags: грамматика, произношение

Is the word "вечер" pronounced like "ˈvʲet͡ɕɨr" or "ˈvʲet͡ɕər" even though the IPA for it is "ˈvʲet͡ɕɪr"?

Comment: "Pronounced like" and "IPA for it" are the same thing, by definition, there is no special Russian IPA. It might make sense to ask "is this IPA transcription right or wrong" (which apparently is what you're really asking), but the way your question is put now, it makes little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination **`чи`** is pronounced similar to the English **`chip`**. But here it's not a pure **`чи`** due to reduction of **`иэ`**. It's in between **`э`** and **`и`**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) Are there any other combinations like this?

Comment: @Edinburgh1 many, there're a few principles of vowel reduction, explained [here](http://archive.is/Ke5yu) in particular, if you don't read Russian (yet), i'll translate for you the principle relating to the cases such as the one you asked about

Answer (score 3):

No it's not.

*[ɨ]* only happens after non-palatalized consonants, and *ч* is always palatalized in Russian.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker, I suppose that "ˈvʲet͡ɕɪr" is more correct pronunciation.